# Why the procesing time increases when using integer data type instead of strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timeit

I have a list of tuples, with more than 0.8 million entries, a sample of which is shown below

```
[('r', 'b', '>', 'ins'),
 ('r', 'ba', '>', 'ins'),
 ('r', 'a', '>', 'del'),
 ('ar', 'b', '>', 'ins'),
 ('ar', 'ba', '>', 'del')]
```

The above list is converted into a Pandas dataframe, and then some subsequent grouping and aggregate operations are performed on it as shown below

```
conDF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tripleeList)
conDF.columns = ["lc","obj","rc","insOrDel"]
conDF["coun"] = 1
groupedConDF = conDF.groupby(["lc","rc","obj","insOrDel"]).count()
```

It is observed that if the final element in each tuple is represented using an integer (say with 1 and 0), instead of using the strings "ins" and "del", then the processing time reaches 10 times that of what is currently required. I have used `%%time` magic in jupyter notebook for obtaining the measures.

Time reported time when using the strings

```
CPU times: user 459 ms, sys: 24.4 ms, total: 484 ms
Wall time: 481 ms
```

The reported time when using the integers

```
CPU times: user 5.77 s, sys: 410 ms, total: 6.18 s
Wall time: 604 ms
```

**Updated**

When modifying the code as suggested by @jezrael, the following is reported

Strings:

```
CPU times: user 966 ms, sys: 45.9 ms, total: 1.01 s
Wall time: 431 ms
```

Integer:

```
CPU times: user 5.72 s, sys: 375 ms, total: 6.09 s
Wall time: 558 ms
```

Modified code:

```
conDF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tripleeList)
conDF.columns = ["lc","obj","rc","insOrDel"]
conDF["coun"] = 1
groupedConDF = conDF.groupby(["lc","rc","obj","insOrDel"], sort=False).size()
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Interesting problem, can you test `conDF.groupby(["lc","rc","obj","insOrDel"], sort=False).size()` for both for prevent  default sorting in `groupby`?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the answer to include your said modification. The trend does not seems to be changed

Comment: hmmm, and what aout createting DataFrame? `%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_records(tripleeList)`

Comment: Then is possible test `%timeit conDF.groupby(["lc","rc","obj","insOrDel"], sort=False).size()`

Comment: For `%timeit conDF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tripleeList)`, for integer results in `325 ms ± 2.14 ms per loop` and for string results in `232 ms ± 757 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
`

Comment: For     `%timeit conDF.groupby(["lc","rc","obj","insOrDel"], sort=False).size()`         , for integer results in `156 ms ± 363 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7` and  for string results in `183 ms ± 384 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: hmmm, so it means for create `DataFrame` is 100ms difference.

Comment: In my opinion it should be expected more time for create mixed columns (3 filled by strings, one filled by integers) like all types are same.